# custom Segue correct way

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, segue

Currently I try to work on a custom segue it should look like:

The [Destination View] should be behind the [Source View], this [Source View] should animate from 100% down to 0.1% and then remove, in the animation time the [Destination View] should also be there in background.
So you see the [Source View] become small in front of the [Destination View] and get removed.

This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class CustomSegueFromBigtoSmall: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {

        let sourceVC = self.sourceViewController
        let destinationVC = self.destinationViewController

        sourceVC.view.addSubview(destinationVC.view)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in

            sourceVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1, 0.1)

            }){ (finished) -> Void in

                destinationVC.view.removeFromSuperview()

                let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.001 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))

                dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    sourceVC.presentViewController(destinationVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
                })
        }

    }

}
```

right now I see my [Source View], that instantly becomes my [Destination View].
 The [Destination View] become small in front of a black background. Once it is "small" it simply appears as full screen.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this in iOS 9 is to make this a presentation (modal) segue with a custom segue implementation. Your custom segue then simply calls `super.perform()` to do the actual presentation. But first, the segue sets itself as the destination's `transitionDelegate` and sets its presentation style to `Custom`. Now you're just doing an ordinary custom transition animation, with your own transitioning delegate and your own UIPresentationController, and you can do whatever you want, in good order.

Comment: Example (from my book) here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p325customSegue/CustomSegue/ViewController.swift